# filter in R is not working with non-standard column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter the table `MyTable` based on the row which has the maximum value of the `Pr(>|t|)` column.

`MyTable`

[image]

Here is the data details in the table:

`str(MyTable)`

[image]

here, I tried to filter the table which has the value less than the maximum of the `Pr(>|t|)`  column.

`filter(MyTable, 'Pr(>|t|)' < max(MyTable$'Pr(>|t|)'))`

[image]

Unfortunately, the filter function seems not working properly. As you can see there are many values in the `Pr(>|t|)` column which is higher than the `max(MyTable$'Pr(>|t|)')`.

I also used the ` after seeing some solution over the internet, but this is showing me some kind of error.

`` filter(MyTable, `Pr(>|t|)` < max(MyTable$'Pr(>|t|)')) ``

[image]

Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: (1) Use backticks not single quotes, as in `filter(MyTable, \`Pr(>|t|)\` < max(\`Pr(>|t|)\`))`. (2) "Never" (almost) use `$`-referencing within dplyr functions that support the NSE. (3) Please don't provide just images of data, don't ask us to transcribe data from images when you have it readily available; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: (4) Type in just `filter` (no parens, no data) and hit enter. I suspect you're accidentally using `stats::filter`, verify with `dplyr::filter(...)`.

Comment: @r2evans - you absolutely can use quotes with `$` - `data.frame('# #' = 1, check.names=FALSE)$'# #'` - it's maybe not good practice but it's not impossible.

Comment: @thelatemail yes of course, I was really thinking "shouldn't" but worded it incorrectly. Thanks.